# How to configure ActiveMQ Artemis as a broker in JBoss 4?

Tags: jboss, activemq-artemis, resource-adapter

I [configured](https://activemq.apache.org/jboss-integration) a standalone **ActiveMQ-5.16.1** to be used as a broker from a **JBoss 4.2.3** server and my **Camel-routes** are able to get messages send from another component a ServerMix-Adaptor to this broker.

I replaced the standalone ActiveMQ-5.16.1 with an **ActiveMQ Artemis-2.17.0** broker and besides few changes to the subscriptions the whole system is working.

I am aware that ActiveMQ 5.16.1 and ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0 are quite different, and I am trying to replace the **activemq-rar-5.4.3.rar** downloaded from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/activemq/activemq-rar/5.4.3/activemq-rar-5.4.3.rar) with the **artemis-rar-2.17.0.rar** downloaded from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/activemq/examples/modules/artemis-rar/2.17.0/artemis-rar-2.17.0.rar). This *.rar* file is deployed under `$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy` together with an `*-ds.xml` file.

In the `*-ds.xml` file 2 connection factories are declared, one for for queues and one for topics. This file references a file contained in the **activemq-rar-5.4.3.rar** *META-INF/ra.xml* and in this file are defined the *connection-factories*.

The problem is that even though the **artemis-rar-2.17.0.rar** contains the same *META-INF/ra.xml* file it's not obvious and not documented what to configure and how to configure it.

I couldn't find an example or a documentation about this.

Comment: Why not simply keep using activemq-rar-5.4.3.rar? ActiveMQ Artemis supports the OpenWire protocol which activemq-rar-5.4.3.rar uses. Why are you forcing a change that isn't strictly necessary, especially on an old system?

Comment: Also, why do Camel routes need to use a JCA RA? Do you have other components in your application which need to use the JCA RA (e.g. MDBs)?

Comment: [Justin-Bertram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8381946/justin-bertram): Yes, in fact we have other components: ServiceMix Aádaptors. The Camel Routes have nothing to do with JBoss. I will edit my Question

Comment: [Justin-Bertram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8381946/justin-bertram): I think that I have understood, that with Artemis things are quite different: it's not possible to configure ConnectionFactories in a JCA RA. Could you please explain to me, which  properties (connectors uso.?) have to be set in the *-ds.xml and ra.xml files? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Some things are different in ActiveMQ Artemis and some things are the same. Artemis supports the OpenWire protocol which is what the activemq-rar-5.4.3.rar uses so **you don't need to change this**.

Comment: [Justin Bertram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8381946/justin-bertram): I did as you said and use *activemq-rar-5.4.3.rar* with *Activemq Artemis*. To be honest, I am eager to know the exact reason, why it's not possible to use *artemis-rar-2.17.0.rar* and how and what to configure in *META-INF/ra.xml*

Comment: I fully expect that it *is* possible to use artemis-rar-2.17.0.rar in JBoss AS 4.x. The issue is that it isn't *necessary*. In other words, you can use your current set up without any problems. Furthermore, JBoss 4.2.3 is over 13 years old now, and I don't have any desire to set up a proof-of-concept with it.